# Dirichlet's problem.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

As far as I know, the Dirichlet problem addresses the construction of the harmonic function $f(x, y)$ inside the Jordan(?) closed loop $C$ such that $f(x, y)$ coincides with the given continuous function $g(x, y)$ on the boundary $C$.

Changing the viewpoint from real variables to the complex variable $z \in {\Bbb C}$ through the real and imaginary parts of the holomorphic function $F(z)$, one might reformulate the setting as follows$\colon$

Given an arbitrary continuous function $g(z)$ on the boundary of the unit-circle $C$, one might try to construct the holomorphic function $F(z)$ inside $C$ such that $F(z) = g(z)$ on the boundary of $C$, i.e. on $|z| = 1$. To the best of my knowledge, Riemann generally solved this by finding the function $F(z)$ which attains the minimum of a certain integral(, which David Hilbert completed).

That is, there would always exist such function $F(z)$ for a given continuous function $g(z)$.

Q. Suppose that $g(z) = \overline{z}$. Then, it follows that $F(z) = 1/z$, which is *not* holomorphic at $z = 0$, i.e. a point inside the unit circle. This seems contradictory to the above statement. What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: The problems are not equivalent as harmonic is a much weaker property than holomorphic ($\bar z$ is harmonic but not holomorphic on the unit disc); in particular, while one can always construct a harmonic function to have limit $g$, you need a strong condition on the Fourier coefficients of $g$ (all such are zero at negative indices) to get a holomorphic extension

Comment: Sorry. I learned that my question has much to do with Hardy space. It seems very profound topics. Thanks. Pierre